# Elegant way to loop through a list of strings, split each string and output except N first elements

Tags: groovy

For instance, this list contains the following strings:

```
array[0]: "text1,text2,text3,text4,text5"
array[1]: "text1,text2,text3,text4,text5,text6,text7"
array[2]: "text1,text2,text3,text4,text5,text6"
```

I need to ignore the first 3 texts and take the rest.

Output should be:

```
"text4,text5"
"text4,text5,text6,text7"
"text4,text5,text6"
```

I suppose I need to split the string using the comma and iterate from 2 till array length for each element.
Is there an elegant way to perform this?

Comment: `output_value = ",".join(input_value.split(",")[3:])` - repeat this for all elements.

Comment: is this `python` or `groovy`?

Comment: The question is for groovy.

Answer (score 1):

For Groovy, you can do something like this:

```
def input = [
    "text1,text2,text3,text4,text5",
    "text1,text2,text3,text4,text5,text6,text7",
    "text1,text2,text3,text4,text5,text6",
]

def result = input.collect {
    it.split(',').drop(3).join(',')
}

result.each { println it }
```

which prints out

```
text4,text5
text4,text5,text6,text7
text4,text5,text6
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use list comprehension

```
array = ["text1,text2,text3,text4,text5", "text1,text2,text3,text4,text5,text6,text7", "text1,text2,text3,text4,text5,text6"]

result = [i.split(",")[2:] for i in array]

print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's in Python. Do you know if it's possible in Groovy? Appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

```
array = array.collect{ i-> i[3..-1] }
```

if you want just to print

```
array.each{ i-> println i[3..-1].join(',') }
```

Answer (score 0):

For lovers of 1-liners:

```
def input = [    
"text1,text2,text3,text4,text5",
"text1,text2,text3,text4,text5,text6,text7",
"text1,text2,text3,text4,text5,text6",
]

def output = input*.split(',')*.getAt( 3..-1 )*.join(',')

output.each this.&println
```

prints:

```
text4,text5
text4,text5,text6,text7
text4,text5,text6
```